Hyperledger Fabric development Jira references inaccessible
There are so many references to jira stories/epics of Hyperledger Fabric open source development in many of the issue discussions, documentation and stackoverflow answers, etc.
These reference URLs are usually like this:
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-17916 OR
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABCE-115
However domain jira.hyperledger.org is no more accessible.
It is very important to study these previous discussions to understand "WHYs" of Hyperledger Fabric. Are these previous development and issue discussions of Fabric are accessible in any other location?
PS: Earlier Hyperledger Fabric project had "free Atlassian Confluence Open Source Project License granted to The Linux Foundation" as mentioned in footer of this doc

Unfortunately Jira licensing changes and subsequent retirement of the Jira instance impacted all the Hyperledger projects. All of the Hyperledger projects have transitioned to GitHub for issue management. If you need to access an old Jira issue, a text archive is available.
